# SQL Update statement no longer working after changing names

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I changed some of the names in my update query and now it no longer works ;(. I get this error.

```
sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id = 42' at line 1",
sqlState: '42000',
index: 0,
sql: "UPDATE developers SET name = 'eyo', absent = '1', WHERE id = 42"
```

I changed slack_id into Name, changed everything like normal, but still doesn't work.

```
    // UPDATE
    app.put("/update", (req, res) => {
      const id = req.body.id;
      const name = req.body.name;
      const absent = req.body.absent;
      db.query("UPDATE developers SET name = ?, absent = ? WHERE id = ?" ,[name, absent, id],
        (err, result) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            res.send(result);
            console.log(result)
          }
        }
      );
    });
```

This Update redirects to my Axios.put

```
const updateDeveloper = () => {
    try {
    setSuccessMessageUpdate('');
    setErrorMessageUpdate('');
    Axios.put(`${url}/update`, { name: name, absent: absent, id: props.id }).then(
      (response) => {
            return (
               {
                id: props.id,
                name: props.name,
                slack_id: props.slack_id,
                absent: props.absent,
                selected: props.selected,
              }
          )
      }
    );
    setSuccessMessageUpdate(`successfully updated developer `);

    } catch (err) {
        setErrorMessageUpdate('something went wrong');
    }
  };
```

I would say the rest of the code is irrelevant because the error is clearly mentioning a database issue. Maybe its a type error? I can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Never-mind I found the issue already. Seems the code is fine but after I saved I forgot to restart node, my bad.